# Javascript onmouseup event not firing as expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I'm working on a tilemap constructor app that uses paint-like functionality to select a tile (src from an image element) and paint it using `mouseup` and `mousedown` event handlers.

For whatever reason the `mouseup` event is not firing as expected. I've read that `mouseup` will not fire if `mousemove` is active, and I am running the `preventDefault` function on `mousemove` and `mousedown`. This seems to work only when I don't have a tile selected.

Here is my event handler function:

```
function setTilemapMouseEvents() {
    var tilemap = document.getElementById('tilemap');

    tilemap.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        window.mouseDown = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    tilemap.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        window.mouseDown = false;
    });
}
```

My tile selecting functions:

```
function TilesetTile(options) {
    this.image = options.image;
    this.symbol = options.symbol;
}

function selectTile(element) {
    var selectedTile = document.getElementsByClassName('selected')[0];
    if (selectedTile !== undefined) {
        selectedTile.classList = 'tileset-tile';
    }
    element.classList += ' selected';
    window.selectedTile = new TilesetTile({image: element.src});
}
```

and my painting function (called by an `onmouseover` event on the tile elements):

```
function paintTile(element) {
    if (window.mouseDown && window.selectedTile) {
        element.innerHTML = '<img src="' + window.selectedTile.image + '" class="tilemap-tile"/>';
    }
}
```

I think this may be a Chrome specific issue. I tried it on Safari real quick and it seemed to work fine. Any insight on what is causing this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I still have no idea what was causing this behavior, but I was able to isolate it to the third line of the `paintTile` function:

```
element.innerHTML = '<img src="' + window.selectedTile.image + '" class="tilemap-tile"/>';
```

Something in this line was interfering with my `mouseup` event being fired. Still have no idea why. I was able to remedy the behavior by wrapping it in a `requestAnimationFrame` call like so:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            element.innerHTML = '<img src="' + window.selectedTile.image + '" class="tilemap-tile"/>';
        });
```

So my issue is solved, but I would still be interested in knowing what could cause this kind of behavior. Please comment if you have any ideas. Thanks,